# Page.GetRouteUrl is returning null

Tags: c#, asp.net

this is Default.aspx  code :

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="Reditect_btn" runat="server" Text="Redirect" OnClick="Redirect_click" />
```

server side :

```
    protected void Redirect_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      string s=Page.GetRouteUrl("Default",null); // here s=null
    }
```

Global.asax

```
 void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}


public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.Clear();
    routes.MapPageRoute("Account", "{PartnerName}/Account/{page}", "~/Account/{page}", false);
    routes.MapPageRoute("Default", "{PartnerName}/{page}", "~/{page}", false);
}
```

`s=null` and i can't understand why :/ can anyone help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong overload.

```
Page.GetRouteUrl("Default");
```

Corresponds to [GetRouteUrl(object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784643(v=vs.110).aspx) where the `object` is your route parameters, you're giving it a route name.

I suspect you need to use:

[GetRouteUrl(string routeName, object routeParameters)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992877(v=vs.110).aspx)

or [GetRouteUrl(
    string routeName,
    RouteValueDictionary routeParameters
)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992933(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: please check out my edit there is an overload method : `Page.GetRouteUrl(string RouteName,object RouteParameters);`

Comment: @Sora - That is not the overload you were using when you first posted the question. And you are passing in `null` instead of the route parameters, what makes you think that will work?

Comment: i am passing null because there is no route parameters to send

Comment: i try to do this : `string s = Page.GetRouteUrl("Default", new {PartnerName="", page = "Default.aspx" });` but still `s=null` i don't understand how this work can u please help

Comment: `null` is not an object, it is a literal representation of a null reference, why are you passing in `null`?. Read the definition of `GetRouteUrl()` - *"Gets the URL that corresponds to a set of route parameters and a route name."* - if it is returning `null` then you clearly do not have a URL that corresponds to the route name and parameters.

Comment: oh i understand now i fixed it by doing this : `routes.MapPageRoute("Default", "{page}", "~/Default.aspx", false);` in Global.asax 
now `string s =Page.GetRouteUrl("Default", new { page = "Default.aspx" });`